# How to have different colours for different button states without using XML?

Tags: android, button, user-interface, colors

I have a button and want it to have different colours depending on if it is pressed or not.

I found this link which explains it nicely:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/build-brighter-apps-using-colour-in-android.html

Now, in my case, I create the button dynamically in my Java code. How can I do it there, without XML?

Comment: take look on this
http://heliodorj.blogspot.com/2009/04/androids-statelistdrawable-example.html

Comment: do you want different text colors or different backgrounds?

Comment: Yes, different background. Sorry I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u are creating the button programmatically also, no need to create the selector without XML. You can use that selector XML file by setting the background to the Button programmatically.

Like:

```
Button button=new Button(this);
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_selector);
```

button_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/green" />
<item android:drawable="@color/red" />
</selector>
```